# Simplifying trigonometric identity having Cosine Inverse of Cosine Theta

Tags: trigonometry

I am looking for the proof for the following relationship (how to obtain RHS) provided that $\beta \geq 1$.

$$-\cos{\theta}\arccos({\dfrac{\cos{\theta}}{\beta}})=\dfrac{1-\cos^2\theta}{\sqrt{\beta^2-\cos^2{\theta}}}$$

I found this in a paper and cross checked by inserting some values, however, could not find a way to derive it. Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn’t seem to hold true when $\beta=1$.

Comment: Once you have corrected the identity (see Tavish's comment) perhaps you could try differentiating.

Comment: Plotting LHS and RHS seems to suggest there is a typo or error in this identity.

Comment: The LHS has a period of $2\pi$ while the RHS has a period of $\pi$. So this suggests there's a major mistake somewhere in the identity.